# how to join to different things (someting.. from and something for ) with and.

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I would like to learn how can I join two different pharse with the word *and* in accorect way.

*The new method shows how to estimate the given model and how to simulate from a given model*

It is not sound good. So, I tried this:

*The new method shows how to estimate and simulate from a given model*

However, it is wrong, as I estimate the model not estimate from the model.

Any help, pelase?

Comment: @F Thomas It is not clear what the two intended meanings you want to join are. I suggest you revise your question into two sentences. Think carefully about whether each is using the best word choices. I have doubts that 'shows how to' is best for what you are trying to say. Also, think carefully about the best prepositions before 'a/the given model'. As a general practice, when you can't get a complex combination of ideas to sound right in one sentence, it may be worthwhile to try breaking them into separate ideas and to then restart the joining process from scratch.

Comment: Yes. Amaizing advice.

Comment: @F Thomas Have a look at the answer by Little Carol. If your input sentence really says what you mean, then her revised version says so in a way that sounds natural to native speakers. Note how she identified repeated words and found ways to avoid repeating them. That is a technique called "parallel structures". You would do well to look up references for what that is and how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The new method shows how to estimate the given model and how to simulate from a given model -F. Thomas

I have no source to support my answer, but this is how I would change it:

*The new method shows how to estimate the given model and simulate from it.*